# Flink - Write a Source for plain Strings

Tags: apache-flink

I've a streaming application with pluggable Source and Sink object

```
public static void build(StreamExecutionEnvironment env, Source<String, ?, ?> source, Sink<MyPojo> sink)
```

Actual source and sink parameters are KafkaSource and KafkaSink respectively

Now I want to test my job. Flink docs refers to SourceFunction and SinkFunction (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/testing/#junit-rule-miniclusterwithclientresource)

I wrote for testing this class

```
private static class TestWordSourceFunction extends RichSourceFunction<String> {
    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<String> sourceContext) {
        sourceContext.collect("hello ciao salut");
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {}
}
```

in order to pass to the build method. But I need a Source object NOT a SourceFunction object.
I found to much complicated create a Source object, I have to implement all these methods

private static class TestWordSource implements Source {

```
@Override
public Boundedness getBoundedness() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public SourceReader createReader(SourceReaderContext sourceReaderContext) throws Exception {
    return null;
}

@Override
public SplitEnumerator createEnumerator(SplitEnumeratorContext splitEnumeratorContext) throws Exception {
    return null;
}

@Override
public SplitEnumerator restoreEnumerator(SplitEnumeratorContext splitEnumeratorContext, Object o) throws Exception {
    return null;
}

@Override
public SimpleVersionedSerializer getSplitSerializer() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public SimpleVersionedSerializer getEnumeratorCheckpointSerializer() {
    return null;
}
```

}

Why there is a connector for plain text Source? Otherwise, can you help me to implement by hand?

Comment: Would create a stream using the `env.fromElements` method be enough to test the job instead of creating a source?

Comment: TY for your answer. Unfortunately I can't because I must respect this interface public `static void build(StreamExecutionEnvironment env, Source<String, ?, ?> source, Sink<MyPojo> sink)`

Answer (score 1):

This is currently rather difficult to do. [FLIP-238: Introduce FLIP-27-based Data Generator Source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-238%3A+Introduce+FLIP-27-based+Data+Generator+Source) is being developed to make this easier.

In the meantime, maybe you can use a `NumberSequenceSource` followed by a map for your testing.